# Wrong glyph with \symbol in LuaLaTeX (?)

Tags: fonts, luatex

Compiling this code with LuaLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\symbol{34}
\symbol{8221}
\end{document}
```

I get

[image: Two identical quotation marks]

And both of these glyphs are #8221. Why? How do I get the glyph at position 34?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mapping of 34 to 8221 is done by the "TeX ligatures" (which also map -- to an endash). To get straight quotes either use `\textquotedbl` or disable the ligatures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\symbol{34}
\symbol{8221}
\textquotedbl
{
\fontspec{Latin Modern Roman}[Ligatures=TeXOff] 
\symbol{34}
\symbol{8221}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]